# Addition of random number and private key using ECC

Tags: elliptic-curve

I have generated keys using ECC. I need to add random number and secret key i.e `x=r+s`. Here's my code:

```
  KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC");
  kpg.initialize(ecSpec, new SecureRandom());
  KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();
  PublicKey pubKey = keyPair.getPublic();
  System.out.println(pubKey);
  PrivateKey privKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
  System.out.println(privKey);
  Random rand = new Random();
  int numNoRange = rand.nextInt();
```

Now I need to add `x=numNoRange+privkey`; but I couldn't add it. Any suggestions for new ideas?

Comment: Question is unclear. You want to add an integer to an ECC private key? To do what? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the `BigInteger` by casting the private key to an `ECPrivateKey` like the following example:

```
    BigInteger s = ((ECPrivateKey) privKey).getS();
```